# neo4j UnderlyingStorageException:Unable to init id generator

Tags: database, neo4j

when I use `BatchInserter` create Relationships, an

`exception occurs`, `BatchInserter is not shutdown.`

Then I run the program again, neo4j sends `exception`

`UnderlyingStorageException:Unable to init id generator.`

What can I do for it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've called shutdown() on your `BatchInserter` instance?